# Kernel of the map $\varphi:G_i\to (G_i/G_i\cap N)/(G_{i+1}/G_{i+1}\cap N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

$\newcommand{\normal}{\triangleleft}$ Let $G$ be a group and $N\normal G$ be a normal subgroup. Suppose $G$ has a subnormal series
$$1 = G_n\normal G_{n-1}\normal\cdots\normal G_1\normal G_0 = G.$$
Then we can construct a subnormal series
$$N = NG_{n}\normal NG_{n-1}\normal\cdots \normal NG_0 = G.$$
Taking quotient by $N$ gives a subnormal series of $G/N$
$$1= NG_n/N\normal NG_{n-1}/N\normal\cdots\normal NG_0/N =G/N.$$
I want to claim that $(NG_{i}/N)/(NG_{i+1}/N)\simeq G_{i}/G_{i+1}$. So I considered a natural projection map
$$\varphi:G_i\to (G_i/G_i\cap N)/(G_{i+1}/G_{i+1}\cap N).$$
I tried to show this map has kernel $G_{i+1}$ but stuck. Can you help?

Comment: You're going to need some restrictions. After all with $N=G$ what you are hoping for is not true.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I see. If for example, $N$ appears in the subnormal series of $G$ then the statement may not be true for some $i$.

Comment: Maybe best to look at case where the $G_{i+1}/G_{i}$ are simple?